# Alternative to using Python in a BASH script for math

Tags: python, bash, math

I have a BASH script that I am writing. I have a variable that is set to the following code:

```
VAR="$(python -c "print (-$STEP+0.25) > ($OLD_OUTPUT_POWER - $NEW_OUTPUT_POWER) > (-$STEP-0.25)")"
```

Where `STEP` is an integer between 10-1, and `OLD_OUTPUT_POWER` and `NEW_OUTPUT_POWER` are decimal numbers (ie: -14.3498306270). I am familiar with Python, and would like do do something like the following strictly in BASH:

```
if ((-$STEP+0.25) > ($OLD_OUTPUT_POWER - $NEW_OUTPUT_POWER) > (-$STEP-0.25)); then
    blah blah
```

Basically if it is true, then do it.

The way I am doing it right now is like this:

```
VAR="$(python -c "print (-$STEP+0.25) > ($OLD_OUTPUT_POWER - $NEW_OUTPUT_POWER) > (-$STEP-0.25)")"

if [[ $VAR == "True" ]]; then
    echo "True"
fi
```

However I would like to be able to do this without utilizing Python. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can easily do this without `python` - just use `awk`, `perl`, `bc`, `dc`, `php`, `octave`, `matlab`, `R` or any number of other command line utilities that do math-y things. If you want to do it without resorting to an external utility, though (i.e. entirely in `bash`), then you'll have to roll your own fixed-point routines, as `bash` doesn't do floating point math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no portable way to do floating point arithmetic in the shell itself.  You will need to resort to an external program.

Instead of Python, you could use AWK which has notably smaller upstart overhead.  Note that it doesn't understand Python's fancy `x < y < z` syntax, so you'll have to re-write it as `x < y && y < z`.  You could define this little Bash function.

```sh
## usage: is_between VALUE UPPER LOWER
##
## Checks whether VALUE is truly between UPPER and LOWER.
##
function is_between {
    awk "BEGIN { exit(!($2 < $1 && $1 < $3)); }"
}
```

It will return the answer via its exit status so it can be used directly inside a conditional.  For example:

```bash
value=3.15
lower=3.14
upper=3.16

if is_between $value $lower $upper
then
    echo "$value is in ($lower, $upper)"
else
    echo "$value is not in ($lower, $upper)"
fi
```

I have written a small benchmark.  Note that I'm actually comparing integers, not reals, so I can compare with the shell builtins.

```bash
#!/bin/sh -eu

what=
if [ ${#} -gt 0 ]
then
    what=$1
fi

case $what in
    awk)
        function is_between {
            awk "BEGIN { exit(!($2 < $1 && $1 < $3)); }"
        }
        ;;
    python)
        function is_between {
            python -c "import sys; sys.exit(not ($2 < $1 < $3));"
        }
        ;;
    *)
        # This one only works for integers!
        function is_between {
            return $((!($2 < $1 && $1 < $3)))
        }
        ;;
esac

i=0
count=0
while [ $i -lt 1000 ]
do
    value="$RANDOM"
    lower="$RANDOM"
    upper="$RANDOM"
    if is_between $value $lower $upper
    then
        count=$(($count + 1))
    fi
    i=$(($i + 1))
done
echo "$count values were in between"
```

Here are my timing results:

```
$ time ./test.sh
152 values were in between

real    0m0.055s
user    0m0.053s
sys 0m0.000s


$ time ./test.sh python
146 values were in between

real    0m33.354s
user    0m27.570s
sys 0m4.047s


$ time ./test.sh awk
157 values were in between

real    0m5.486s
user    0m3.503s
sys 0m0.723s
```

As you can see, the differences are quite dramatic…

Answer (score 0):

use `bc` if the decimal matters otherwise use the bash extension `$((ANARITHMETICEXPRESSION))`.